# How to set alarm manager consistent in android?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am setting alarm manager by this method:

```
public void setAlarmManager(Context context, Intent intent, long repeat) {

        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), repeat, pendingIntent);
    }
```

by this method i am sending sms in a specific number after a fixed amount of time.But this method doesn't remain consistent.Specially when the goes to sleep mode it doesn't work.how can i make this continous that it will also work in sleep mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AlarmManager` with a `_WAKEUP` alarm only guarantees that it will keep the device awake if you use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`.

If your work will take only a handful of milliseconds, switch your `Service` to a `BroadcastReceiver`.

If your work will take more than a few milliseconds, consider [using my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), which offers a pattern for allowing `_WAKEUP` alarms to reliably get their work done.